# Rendering video from image sequence. The result is low res and with wrong colors

Tags: rendering, animation, resolution

I render my animations as "png" at first and then I put them together with the sound. There is nothing wrong with that.

But I have been trying to figure this out for so long, and still can't do it. 
When I render, the video comes out with less resolution. AND it literally ruins all the colors in it.

The Colors (Normal and after rendering):

[image: Colours]

Here is my settings for it as well:

[image: Settings]

I am so desperate for help at this point. I would be SO happy if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I have no idea what i did. Was extremely confused. Thought that it was a mistake i guess?

Comment: using cycles or blender internal? What color sampling for the PNG used (8bit/16bit)? Did you compare the PNG with FFMPEG encoding outside blender (Blender display of images is cannot be used seriously for color comparison)? Did you change the video processing of your video player? Did you try the video with different players? Also, can you attach one of the PNG rendering as well as a few seconds of the video encoded?

Comment: I just found out that its something about the video player that is wrong. When i posted the video on YouTube it looked totally fine. Pretty weird stuff. But still @Bruno thanks a lot for taking your time to try and help me!

Comment: Cool glad you found the issue. Can you add your own answer? That will help the next viewer.